# How to determine the encryption scheme used when given a cipher text and the key

Tags: cryptography, encryption

For a homework assignment, I am asked to determine the algorithm used to generate a given cipher text. The key is also given. Currently, I am working down a list of simple encryption algorithms and semi-blindly testing different decryption arrangements in an attempt at retrieving the given plain text.

Is there a better way to go about this process? I've read pages of Google results on the topic and haven't come across anything that explained a better process than what I'm already doing. Thus far I've run multiple levels of linguistical analysis upon the cipher text and am trying to plug in logical values into the encrypted message to decrypt it.

This is built around basic cryptographic systems, nothing at the level of public key encryption or DES.

Even if I can get the original message, how will that show the encryption scheme that was used?

Comment: Since you eliminate DES, I am guessing that the goal is to figure out which non-standard (creative) function encrypted the message? Can you also eliminate AES and other established symmetric algorithms? 

If so, I would suggest trying out logical operators such as XOR against the key and data. Hopefully that will lead you somewhere.

Comment: As far as I know, it could be any number of "simple" encryption schemes. IE: Caesar ciphers, Playfair ciphers, Hill ciphers, etc. I have tried XOR (and others) between the key and cipher, nothing of value that I could detect was revealed.

Comment: What do you know about the plaintext? Do you have a finite list of ciphers? Could it be something entirely fabricated?

Comment: After running some linguistic analyses upon the cipher text and a few brute force searches upon some educated guesses at alphabetical mappings, I was able to decrypt the plain text. I am still unsure as to how the key is related though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to identify encryption algorithm used in ciphertext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366727/how-to-identify-encryption-algorithm-used-in-ciphertext)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer would be there is nothing wrong with trying various different algorithms out and seeing what works.

Cryptanalysis is like solving a puzzle, not a step by step process. You try things, you see what works, what you think gets you closer. It is absolutely trial and error based on knowledge of the potential algorithms, patterns and techniques and the reasons for them. Differential cryptanalysis, a modern technique, basically amounts to trying various combinations of keys and plaintexts within an algorithm and looking at the differences to see if you can find patterns.

From your comments, I think you're facing a [vigenere cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) or some similar variant thereof. In this case, the key is important because essentially a vigenere cipher is a set of caesar ciphers and the length of the key determines the number of these ciphers. Now, the rules of the scheme in question will tell you exactly *what* cipher it is, but that's the basis of it.

Comment: Could you move that second sentence to the end of the second paragraph? I was really confused about what you were trying to get at, at first.